# sortedArrayUsingFunction doesn't sort properly

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Based on an `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableDictionary`s, I try to sort it based on a key by ascending order. the key is called `Product Sale Price` and it's returned from server as a string like `$350`. So I substring the first character to compare int values:

```
//Sorting function
NSInteger priceComparator(NSMutableDictionary *obj1, NSMutableDictionary *obj2, void *context){
    int v1 = [[[obj1 valueForKey:@"Product Sale Price"]substringFromIndex:1] intValue];
    int v2 = [[[obj2 valueForKey:@"Product Sale Price"]substringFromIndex:1] intValue];
    NSLog(@"v1, v2: %i | %i",v1,v2);
    if (v1 > v2){

        NSLog(@"v2 is smaller: <%i>",v2);
        return v2;
    }
    else if (v1 < v2){

        NSLog(@"v1 is smaller: <%i>",v1);
        return v1;   
    }
    else
        return NSOrderedSame;
}


//Somewhere in the code
arrayProduct = (NSMutableArray*)[arrayProduct sortedArrayUsingFunction:priceComparator context:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",arrayProduct);//The array is not sorted as expected, still random order
```

So basically, the order is not affected somehow although I debugged that step b step and all comparisons are correct. Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**

Here is some items of `arrayProduct`:

```
(
    {
        "Product ID" = 15119;
        "Product Sale Price" = "$395";
    },

    {
        "Product ID" = 16897;
        "Product Sale Price" = "$75";
    }
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return `NSOrderedAscending` and `NSOrderedDescending` instead of `v1` and `v2`. If the sort ends up in reverse order - swap which of the two you return.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sort descriptor for sorting array like below code here key is key of parameter on which you want to sorting array. **e.g you want to sort by name then key is "name"**

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"key" ascending:YES] autorelease];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]init];
sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [Array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```